# What do the quarter circle and full circle icons mean?

Tags: loop-hero

Next to the resources satchel icon on the top bar, there are icons for a quarter circle and a full circle with numbers next to them. What do the numbers by the quarter circle and full circle mean?

[image: backpack with quarter and full circle icons]

Comment: I believe it represents the number of 'small resources' vs 'large resources' you have. If you click the satchel to expand it, what do you see with them all splayed out?

Comment: @Seiyria [You appear to be correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vegtt.png). Feel free to post an answer and use the screenshot if you would like. (I've also encountered a a third type of resource since posting).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The full circle represents the number of "large resources" as @Seiyria mentioned, or the "raw materials". The quarter circle represents the "small resources" or the "processed resources".

Screenshot given by @Stevoisiak:

[image]